# select JSON object based on ui-router url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

EDIT: Better phrasing of the question. I am basically looking at how to use the variable stored in $scope.item (grabbed from URL using $stateParams) to access the related object in the products JSON array.

Alright so I have used a combination of ui-router and ng-ref so that when you click a product on the "#/shop/" page it creates a URL "#/shop/productname" that when navigated to opens a blank div on the page that is meant to contain details about the product mentioned in the URL.

The issue I am having, and I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking, is how to get the corresponding data based on the name in the URL? So that I can display product name/price etc that is stored in a JSON object?

Any help would help a ton! It's very possible I am going about this all wrong so please refer me in the right direction if you feel I could choose a better path.

HTML:

shop.html URL: #/shop

```
...
    <a ng-repeat="item in businesses | filter:{cat: cat} | filter:query" 
       ng-class="{active: item.selected}"
       ng-href="#/shop/{{item.link}}" 
       ng-click="selectedItem(item)">
        ...
    </a>
    <div ui-view></div>
...
```

product.html URL: #/shop/productName

```
<h1>item.name</h1>
<h2>item.price</h2>
```

App.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router'
])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/shop');
    $stateProvider
        .state('shop',{
            url: '/shop',
            templateUrl: 'templates/shop.html',
            controller: 'starWarsCtrl'
        })
        .state('shop.item',{
            url: '/:item',
            templateUrl: 'templates/three-quarter-page.html',
            controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
                $scope.item = $stateParams.item;
            }
        })
     ;
})

.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "index":1,
        "link":"product1",
        "price":"TBD",
     }
  ];

  $scope.selectItem = function (selectedItem){
      _($scope.products).each(function (item){
          item.selected = false;
          if (selectedItem === item){
              selectedItem.selected = true;
          }
      })
  };

}) /*End Controller*/

});
```

Comment: It looks like you have the item from the url in $scope.item.  Are you just asking how to use that variable to get the object from the products array?

Answer (score 0):

This will get the selected item for you, assuming you match by the name.

```
$scope.selectedItem = _.where($scope.products, {name: $scope.item});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I were you I would use angular `service` to share data between controllers
and this service will handle the data for me so when I change the product it will return the item object

```
angular.module('app').factory('productsService', function () {
    self = this;
    self.products = [{
    "name": "Product 1",
    "index":1,
    "link":"product1",
    "price":"TBD",
   }];
   this.findByLink = function(link){
        // loop through your data
       //  returns what found or null 
   }
return {
     products : this.products 
     findById : this.findById
}

});
```

and inject this service in each controller

```
.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, productsService) {
  $scope.products = productsService.products;
  ..........
```

and to anther one

```
.controller('productCtrl', function ($scope, productsService, $stateParams) {

  $scope.item = productsService.findById($stateParams.link);
  ..........
```

Comment: Is the `findById` in the service return and productCtrl supposed to be `findByLink`? Just trying to understand where that comes from. And my methods of looping through data to find object with matching link have been unsuccessful. How would you recommend doing so? I have created the factorie though which is working great.